# install vue in laravel such file or directory

Tags: laravel

I want install Vue in Laravel but when I run `php artisan ui vue`
get this error

```
copy(.../resources/js/bootstrap.js): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I try many ways like

```
rm -rf vendor composer.lock && composer install
composer clearcache
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: can you share your app.js and webpack.mix? Can you also check if .../resources/js/bootstrap.js exists? And for the last, if you are installing vue, can you run this command first with no errors?:  npm i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run following command

`composer install --ignore-platform-req=php`